# Line numbers on code samples

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to get line numbers on code snippets? Line numbers would make it a lot easier to reference code in the comments section where brevity is important. It is also a lot more accurate way to refer back to a code snippet. I know that editing the code could make a reference inaccurate but it seems like once a snippet is posted they are rarely edited.

```cpp
// this style of code snippet doesn't have line numbers (even with the lang-cpp tag)
```

```
// Neither does this one
```

Even if only 1 style like the 3 back ticks supported it, then question answers could go back and add the ticks in to get the numbering easily.

Comment: [Meta.SE question (originally from meta.SO in 2009)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings). While this seems like something that could/should be just a userscript, having it built-in makes it a common asset where you might refer to line numbers in a question and have some reasonable expectation that your readers will *get* the reference without special effort.

Comment: The main reason I bring it up is: Everywhere I work with code, GitHub, code editors, even emacs there are line numbers. Except here. Where its absence seems glaring. Limiting it to specific tags suggests a level of user sophistication that wouldn't require extra effort. While limiting it to user scripts makes it unusable for a more general audience.